# How can I add style to a parent component?

Tags: angular

Since stylesheets which are referenced in your angular.json's styles[] cannot be referenced in a Component's styleUrls[] decorator, what is an accurate way to be able to style children in a parent component from the parent component's main CSS file?

EX.

```
app-component > parent-component > child-component
```

I want to be able to style whatever is inside the parent component's template (including the code that is inside the child component's HTML selector ) without compromising the stylesheet referenced in the angular.json file. (styles.css)

I have tried to set either of these properties in the decorator of my parent component's TS file...

```
encapsulation : ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom
```

```
encapsulation : ViewEncapsulation.Native
```

However, the problem lies in the fact that if I use either of these methods, the styles inside the angular.json file will not apply to the parent container or any of the children! Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The `ViewEncapsulation` you're looking for is `ViewEncapsulation.None`.

Comment: I'm aware of ``` ViewEncapsulation.None ``` however, in this case, I don't want the parent of my parent container to be able to render the code inside the stylesheet. I don't want the stylesheet to be 'Global' I just want it to be available for the parent container and its children

Answer (score 0):

You do not really want to change the style of your parent component, you want to change it state, and then change the design depending on the state.

For that, simply use an `EventEmitter` in your children component and play with it on your parent component.

---

Else, if you won't use an emitter to change the state (and the parent template) then you cannot do it by following Angular standards and guidelines.

The Angular component structure is made to create a hierarchy between every component. By following the standards, the only thing that a component can do to it parent is to emit information.